# Using recursion to write a method that creates a path in Java

Tags: java, recursion

I wrote a method called "createPath" which takes an integer and a string as parameters. It should work like this:

```
createPath(0,"a.txt") //prints out "a.txt"
createPath(1,"a.txt") //prints out "folder1/a.txt"
createPath(2,"a.txt") //prints out "folder1/folder2/a.txt"
createPath(3,"a.txt") //prints out "folder1/folder2/folder3/a.txt"
```

and so on....
This method uses recursion, so there is no for/for each/while loops.
And this is my code:

```
public static void recursion(int n, String s) {
    if (n == 0) {
        System.out.print(s);
    } else if (n==1){
        System .out.print("folder1/" + s);
    } else {
        if(n>2) {
            recursion(n-1,s);                
            System.out.print("folder" + n + "/");                      
        } else {
            System.out.print("folder1/folder2/");
        }      
        System.out.print(s);  
    }
}

//expected output: folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/a.txt
//actual output: folder1/folder2/a.txtfolder3/a.txtfolder4/a.txtfolder5/a.txt
```

My problem is that I failed to print out the given string for only once at the end of the output. How to modify the code so that I can get the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need so many if-else.

```java
public static void recursion(int n, String s) {
        if (n == 0) {
            System.out.print(s);
        } else {
            recursion(n - 1, "folder" + n + "/" + s);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It would print in following order: folder5/folder4/folder3/folder2/folder1/a.txt

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve as following:

```java
public static void recursion(int n, String s, int start) {
    if (n == 0) {
        System.out.print(s);
    } else {
        System.out.print("folder" + start + "/"); 
        recursion(n-1,s,start+1);      
    }
}
```

Input:

```
recursion(5, "a.txt", 1);
```

Output:

```
folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/a.txt
```

Comment: @yenyun035 if you upvote answer, you will motivate us to answer your questions in future as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code :

```
static String rec(int limit, String fileName, StringBuilder stringBuilder) {
        if (limit == 0)
            return stringBuilder.append(fileName).toString();
        else {
            int newLimit = limit - 1;
            return rec(newLimit, fileName, stringBuilder.append("folder" + limit + "/"));
        }

    }
```

Calling the above method :

```
rec(10, "a.txt", new StringBuilder())
```

output:

```
folder10/folder9/folder8/folder7/folder6/folder5/folder4/folder3/folder2/folder1/a.txt
```

Comment: Does it help in solving your problem?